# How can I declare a @property but prevent its ivar from being created?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have class `A`, which exposes a way of getting and setting an object of type `Foo`. In property parlance, I generally declare this in the interface:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) Foo * foo;
```

This (in modern ObjC) generates both the accessors and an ivar, `_foo` for storage.

If I want to do custom work in the accessors, I can implement one or both of them myself. But what if I not only want to do custom work, I actually don't want the ivar? In other words, I'm doing something else with the Foo object, like handing it back and forth to another internal object that I'm composed with. I don't actually need to keep storage for `foo` in the instance of `A` at all.

It seems like I have two choices:

1. Declare the property, implement both accessors, and simply ignore the fact that the compiler creates storage for `_foo`, and never use it.
2. Declare my accessors explicitly: `- (Foo *)foo` and `- (void)setFoo:(Foo *)foo` in the interface, like I used to in pre-modern ObjC.

The first seems inelegant at runtime, and the second seems inelegant in the declaration (where I'd probably now have a mix of properties and property-like accessors).

Is there a way to declare a property and have it serve as purely a declaration?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you override both the setter and getter and don't use the variable within the setter and getter, a variable will not be created.

For example, if you have a class for which you want a `firstName` and `lastName` property, but perhaps also a `setter` and `getter` for a `fullName` property, if your `fullName` setter simply parses a string into `firstName` and `lastName` and sets these properties to that (and never stores the full string into a `fullName` variable), and your `fullName` getter simply `returns` the concatenated `firstName` + `lastName` and never uses a `fullName` variable, one will never be created.

This is according to Apple's official documentation.  [Scroll down to "You Can Implement Custom Accessor Methods"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html)

Comment: You're right! Thanks for the doc pointer, I'd missed that. I do find this behavior a little magical for my taste, but glad to know it.

Comment: And as you may have noticed in the documentation, you can declare the property as `readonly` or `writeonly` and overwrite just that accessor and avoid having the variable created.

Comment: The compiler was complaining that the "Ivar which backs the property is not referenced." This answer helped me realize the issue: I had incorrectly capitalized the name of my property's setter method. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Use the `@dynamic` keyword in the implementation file. The usual discussion of `@dynamic` describes it as not creating the *accessors* at compile time. Not usually mentioned is that is **also has the effect of doing nothing to create storage** for the property, which is exactly what is desirable in this case.

```
@implementation A
@dynamic foo;

- (Foo *)foo 
{
   // get a Foo from somewhere and return it.
}

- (void)setFoo:(Foo *)foo
{
   // do something with foo
}

@end
```

(Note: answered my own question since I discovered this while writing up the question and it seemed interesting and nonobvious.)

Answer (score 3):

`@dynamic` is probably the way to go.

However, there are two other ways you can do this as well:

1. An Unimplemented Category

   You can use an un-implemented category to declare a property, but not get the backing storage:

   ```
   @interface Foo : NSObject
   @end

   @interface Foo (UnimplementedProperties)
   @property (strong) id bar;
   @end

   @implementation Foo
   @end
   ```

   By not declaring the implementation of the category (`@implementation Foo (UnimplementedProperties)`), the properties won't be synthesized.
2. A Protocol

   You can declare the properties on a protocol, and then make your class conform to that protocol.  This has the same effect as the unimplemented category: the methods are declared, but the properties are not synthesized.

   ```
   @protocol FooProperties <NSObject>
   @property (strong) id bar;
   @end

   @interface Foo : NSObject <FooProperties>

   @end
   ```

Comment: Great points, thanks. The downside of these is that consumers of the object see this distinction in the header, but it shouldn't be any business of my callers how I manage a property as long as I behave rationally from their point of view.

Comment: @BenZotto agreed, which is why you should probably use `@dynamic`. But these approaches have their uses too. :)

Comment: Yup, and it hadn't occurred to me that these patterns have the side effect of doing what I was after. Thanks. (Anyways, turns out maybe we're both trying too hard in any case, see @nhgrif's answer.)

Comment: Seems really dangerous to recommend an unimplemented category as a solution to anything.

Comment: @HeathBorders really? They're all over when you use Core Data and generate your managed object subclasses. They're a quick and convenient way to declare dynamic methods (so you avoid missing method warnings) but still not have to implement them (because you're using dynamic method resolution).

Comment: Aren't class extensions better for this? Why does CoreData do it this way? Declaring something with a category and not implementing it lying to the linker?

Comment: @HeathBorders Putting it in a class extension means the property would be automatically synthesized as part of the primary `@implementation` block.  There are times when you want to declare a method/property but not actually implement it (this is literally what `@dynamic` does).  It's rare to need it, but it can be incredibly useful.

Comment: @DaveDeLong but the CoreData implementations put `@dynamic` in for all of the properties anyway. Why put the properties in an unimplemented category AND make them `@dynamic`?

Comment: @HeathBorders Core Data uses unimplemented categories for relationship accessors.  For example, if you have a to-many relationship called "employees", then Core Data generates an unimplemented category that defines the `addEmployeesObject:`, `removeEmployeesObject:`, `addEmployees:`, and `removeEmployees:` methods.  The `@dynamic` would only take define the `setEmployees:` and `employees` methods, but not the KVC-compliant accessors.

Comment: @DaveDeLong derp. I forgot about those. So this is the officially blessed way to do runtime method implementations with compile-time checking then? Thanks for being so patient with me.

Comment: @HeathBorders This is *a* way to do runtime method implementations with compile-time checking (protocols are another way).  Since it's "how Objective-C works", it's a legit approach.