# How to declare a property that has no physical backing in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c

Say I have a property that has no physical backing. That is, it has no internal pointer. An example setter and getter would be:

```
- (void)setImage:(UIImage*)image
{
    self.imageView.image = image;
    [self setNeedsLayout];
}

- (UIImage*)image
{
    return self.imageView.image;
}
```

How would I declare the property in the header file to make it clear to other co-workers that this property has no physical backing?

```
@property(nonatomic, ????) UIImage* image;
```

I know that if I use copy, assign, or strong, it makes no difference and my code still works. But it is not clear to other people reading the code what my intentions are.

Comment: What do you mean by physical backing?

Comment: Why don't you use a @protocol ?

Comment: Because you can't declare properties with a @protocol.

Comment: By no "physical backing", I mean there is no `_image` pointer autogenerated for me. I don't store the value of the property directly, however it is stored indirectly in some other object.

Comment: @Pwner then use the readonly property if you don't want others to make changes to that property but only to be able to read it. And declare the same property again in your private interface (extension) and use readwrite so you can make changes to it privately.

Comment: @Cyrille: "Because you can't declare properties with a @protocol." [Yes, you can.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKAnnotation_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfp/MKAnnotation/coordinate)

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19625162/how-can-i-declare-a-property-but-prevent-its-ivar-from-being-created

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say `strong`, because internally the imageView has a `strong` link to its image:

```
@interface UIImageView : UIView
[...]
@property(nonatomic,retain) UIImage *image;                                                     
[...]
@end
```

Comment: So you'd say it changes depending on the internal implementation. However it's kept internally should be exposed in the header.

Comment: @Pwner Yes, the implementation matters. What you put in the `@property` line is defining a contract between the class and the client. If you declared it `strong` but implemented it (directly or indirectly) as `weak` - or visa versa, there would be problems. So yes, make it match your ultimate implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Clients of this class have no reason to know -- indeed, *should not care* -- how the class stores any of its data.

They should treat this property just as they treat any other property, whether it actually has a backing ivar or not. All they need to know is how to get and set it, and whether the class will take ownership when the property is set.

In this case the class has an (indirect) owner relationship to the image, so `strong` is the correct choice from the ownership specifiers.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImage * image;
```

Comment: The question seems to be about whether to use `strong`, `weak`, or `assign`, or `copy`. The client does care about that.

Comment: I see, @rmaddy; I didn't get that interpretation, but I'll make my answer more clear along those lines.

Comment: See the very last two sentences of the question under the last line of code.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare it only as either `readonly` or `readwrite`. The compiler won't generate an instance variable (storage) for it, if you never use it. See also [How can I declare a @property but prevent its ivar from being created?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19625162/how-can-i-declare-a-property-but-prevent-its-ivar-from-being-created) (and look at [Apple's doc here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html) and scroll to "You Can Implement Custom Accessor Methods") If you really want to specify a retain type, then objects are generally retained--as indeed is yours-- so "strong" is fine, although it will be ignored by the compiler (which you've seen, because any of them work the same).

Design-wise, it's not actually important (or desirable) to indicate to users of the class that there's "no storage" for it. Why should they care, or behave any differently? External to the object, it should just look like any other property, no matter how it is derived.